# Multiple interfaces to the same network in Docker

Tags: docker

Is it possible to have a single container connected with multiple interfaces to the same network?

If I run `docker network connect --ip <ip> net container` twice with two different IPs I get the error "endpoint with name.. already exists in network..". Hence I guess it is not possible, but since I could not find a definite answer to this question I ask it here.

Update: I tried also with the `--alias` flag to specify unique aliases, which did not help, it resulted in the same error.

Comment: did you try with the --alias flag?

Comment: Yes, same error.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This feels like an X-Y question.

Comment: I want to emulate a set of "clients" that consume services from another container. I would then have one interface per client and be able to enforce rate-limits and other traffic shaping constraints on each interface using tc. Of course I can do the same with having one container per client, but since I am looking at having a large set of clients, it would be useful to be able to have more than 1 interface per client container.